# how do i uninstall google pagespeed installed in ubuntu with nginx?

Tags: nginx, pagespeed

I have 2 questions

How do i purge/uninstall Nginx I compiled on ubuntu?

I did install google pagespeed on ubuntu web server running nginx, according to the following tutorial https://github.com/pagespeed/ngx_pagespeed and https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/configuration

How do i purge this package without affecting my server?

Your assistance will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To uninstall pagespeed, build a new version of nginx [from source](https://github.com/pagespeed/ngx_pagespeed) but without the `--add-module=$HOME/ngx_pagespeed-1.8.31.2-beta` argument to `./configure` that tells the nginx build process to include pagespeed.

Alternatively, you can remove all `pagespeed` directives from your configuration, which has almost the same effect as uninstalling it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to uninstall ngx_pagespeed if you don't want to use it, just add to your host.conf file

```
pagespeed off;
```

If for some other reasons you want to remove it, Just enter:

```
nginx -V
```

You will get a result something like this:

```
configure arguments: --add-module=/root/custom-nginx/nginx-1.10.2/src/http/modules/ngx_pagespeed --prefix=/etc/nginx --sbin-path=/usr/sbin/nginx --modules-path=/usr/lib64/nginx/modules --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --pid-path=/var/run/nginx.pid --lock-path=/var/run/nginx.lock --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/client_temp --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/proxy_temp --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/fastcgi_temp --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/uwsgi_temp --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/scgi_temp --user=nginx --group=nginx --with-file-aio --with-threads --with-ipv6 --with-http_addition_module --with-http_auth_request_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_flv_module --with-http_gunzip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_mp4_module --with-http_random_index_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_secure_link_module --with-http_slice_module --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_sub_module --with-http_v2_module --with-mail --with-mail_ssl_module --with-stream --with-stream_ssl_module --with-cc-opt='-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic'
```

Remove --add-module=/root/custom-nginx/nginx-1.10.2/src/http/modules/ngx_pagespeed

And compile again